# Formula for exponents?

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a formula for exponents that works with both negative and positive powers? I have tried searching online but only found: If positive do this, if negative do this. 
Thanks.

EDIT: Ah, I see why I wasnt clear enough. I need a formula for exponents but it only needs to work with positive and negative **integers**.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific, I don't think in this generality there's a meaningful answer to your question.

Comment: This is a genuine question, not trying to be hurtful: How can I be more specific? I need a formula to generate a^b that works universally (Of course the formula can't be a^b)

Comment: A formula for exponents in what context?  What is $a$?  What is $b$?  Why is $a^b$ not simplified enough as it is?

Comment: Can you show us an example of a "formula" that works for you if $a$ and $b$ are both positive?  Just so we can have a better idea of what you mean.

Comment: As Gregory said: What kind of formula specifically? This might help: What kind of context are you working in? Why were you looking for exponent formulae?

Comment: You could look into algorithms for functions like "Math.Pow" that make such calculations.

Comment: As an example of a formula that works only for positives:
$b^n = \underbrace{b \times \cdots \times b}_n$

Comment: @user240331 that particular formula is a direct consequence of the property that $b^1=b$ and that $b^{n+m} = b^n\cdot b^m$.  The result that you write though is *only* valid when $n$ is a natural number like 1,2,3,4,5,...  (after all, what does it mean to multiply something four-and-a-half times?)

Comment: Your edit doesn't help at all. At least, it not helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\large
x^n=
\begin{cases}
\underbrace{x\cdot x \cdots x \cdot x}_{n \text{ times}}& n>0\\ 
1 &n =0\\
\frac{1}{\underbrace{x\cdot x \cdots x \cdot x}_{|n| \text{ times}}}&n<0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Just pointing out,  $x^n\neq \frac{1}{x^n}$ unless $x^n = 1$.  Also, you can use & to offset things in cases.  I'm taking the liberty of editing the mistakes and odd typesetting.  Furthermore, you had "$x>0$" instead of $n>0$.  Your third case seemed out of place as well.  $x^n=\frac{1}{x^{-n}}$ is always true, not just when $n<0$.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the power series for the exponential function.  In particular, we have
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
It would therefore follow that (for $a > 0$),
$$
a^{x} = e^{\ln(a)x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{[\ln(a)]^k x^k}{k!}
$$
For other values of $a$, the value $a^x$ is not guaranteed to "make sense" in the context of the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiation in general follows the following rules:

For all nonzero $x$

- $x=x^1$
- $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$
- $x^0 = 1$

From these basic properties, we can see several things:

- $x^{-1}\cdot x = x^{-1}\cdot x^1 = x^0 = 1$ so $x^{-1}$ is in fact the multiplicative inverse of $x$
- $x^n = x\cdot x^{n-1}$
- $x^n = \underbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}_{n~x\text{'s}}$ for a natural number $n$
- $x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}$ since multiplicative inverses are unique.
- $x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$
- $(x^a)^b = x^{a\cdot b}$

For defining the exponentiation function for $x^n$ where $n$ is an integer, we can use the third result I listed above to relate it to multiplication and the fifth result if it were negative to simplify it first.  For using exponents that are not integers, it requires a more careful definition, such as what Omnomnomnom provided in his answer.

---

A short example that uses several of these properties:

> Simplify the following expression: $$\frac{2^3\cdot 3^1\cdot 2^1}{2^{-1}\cdot 3^1}$$

Answer: $2^{5}=32$

Comment: May be this answer is better for an unclear understanding.